# Use of CHANNEL function instead of CDR function in asterisk 13

Tags: asterisk, channel, ivr

I am using Asterisk 13 and facing this warning :

WARNING[10303] func_cdr.c: Using the CDR function to set 'accountcode' is deprecated. Please use the CHANNEL function instead.

Anyone please guide how can I use CHANNEL function to set 'accountcode'?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
CHANNEL(accountcode)=foo
```

**Further reading:**

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Function_CHANNEL